# Nginx taking issue with particular file resulting in 405, express app crashes

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I stumbled upon a really weird behaviour of my server/express app.
Recently implemented a image-upload to the app. Works wonderful.

Just now i tried to upload another picture to see my nginx server answering with an 405 error. Also the express app crashes with the error (using sharp for image handling):

```
(sharp:15): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "0" of type 'gint' is invalid or out of range for property 'Q' of type 'gint'
```

Something about this very particular picture seems to be wrong, so nginx takes an issue with it. Tried to reproduce that error with any other picture, file form, naming... no success. But even if that file has a problem and nginx takes an issue with it, I don't understand what causes my express-app to crash.

In my local development environment uploading that picture works perfectly fine (no nginx envolved).

So, if it IS nginx causing the problem, why is my app crashing? What does nginx do to the file that makes the app crash (see strange error above)?

Would love to have your input on this, thanks.

Comment: See if you can add some logs about the issues using techniques discussed in http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/. This would help see what it sends to your app

Comment: @TarunLalwani Brillant, just looked at my logs. I guess here is the answer: "[error] 20649#20649: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,". Does that mean my express-app crashed while respondig? So the reason is my app after all, nginx just shows that error because it interprets the express-apps response like that? Next question ist, why is it not crashing in my local dev environment?

Comment: Yes looks like it. You should enable more logging on the app side using environment variable `export NODE_DEBUG=cluster,net,http,fs,tls,module,timers` and then run your app this will give much more log and you can see where the app crashes